Using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize / deserialize an interface
Given the interface and the class below
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "name";

    public string Value { get; set; } = "value";
}

I can use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize a Foo object easily
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFoo foo = new Foo();

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

However, since I need to deserialize this json later on, I thought I would need a custom converter for IFoo, since the deserializer can't know which type of IFoo the given object is.
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class FooConverter : JsonConverter<IFoo>
{

    public override IFoo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IFoo? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (existingValue!.Name == "name")
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(reader)!;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IFoo? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "name";

    public string Value { get; set; } = "value";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo foo = new Foo();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFoo>(json)!;
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedObj.Name);
    }
}

I tried to keep the default serialization logic in WriteJson but it throws a
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected with type 'Foo'. Path ''.'
Deserialization doesn't work too. What am I doing wrong?

Could use the JsonSubTypes package https://stackoverflow.com/a/49214090/14868997

JSON has no types. Both JSON.NET and System.Text.Json solve this by emitting type information in a $type attribute. It's better to use the built-in support instead of rolling your own. In .NET 7 you can specify your own type discriminator instead of emitting the type name

Another option is to deserialize to a JObject, determine the type and then use JObject.ToObject<Foo> to deserialize to the type you want.

i rewrote converter little bit. and had to use loop ignore. also, in converter for  this example I am replacing values.
void Main()
{
    IFoo foo = new Foo();
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{}").Dump();
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}


public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "name";
    public string Value { get; set; }= "value";
}

class FooConverter : JsonConverter<IFoo>
{

    public override IFoo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IFoo existingValue = null, bool hasExistingValue = false, JsonSerializer serializer  = null)
    {
        IFoo foo = new Foo();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            reader.Read();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                    throw new FormatException("Expected a property name, got: " + reader.TokenType);
                string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
                reader.Read();

                values.Add(propertyName, reader.Value);
                reader.Read();
            }
            foo.Name = foo.Name + "_XXX"; //for text to show override
        }
        else
            throw new FormatException("Expected start of object or start of array");

        reader.Read();
        return foo;

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IFoo value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //serializer.Serialize(writer, value);

        JObject jo = new JObject();
        Type type = value.GetType();
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                object propVal = prop.GetValue(value, null);
                if (propVal != null)
                {
                    jo.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(propVal + "_xxx", serializer));
                }
            }
        }
        jo.WriteTo(writer);

    }
}




Since you're using Newtonsoft.json which supports configuring this behavior via the JsonSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling option. learn more here,
Example:
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
};
    
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (object, settings);

This answer helped me to fix this issue when i had it, a really good one too.

Have you actually tried this with OP's setup? The issue is not related to reference loops in OP's data but to the loops for type converters.
